# iOS: Keyboard appear automatically in ios8 but not able to resign textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Keyboard appear automatically after received web service result in iOS8.3 while using xcode6.3.1 / 6.3.2. But it work correctly in previous versions.

Am using following code to resign keyboard when touch inside of view

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint ForgotTxt_call = [touch locationInView:userFrgtPwdTxtFld];
    BOOL isForgotTxt = [userFrgtPwdTxtFld pointInside:ForgotTxt_call withEvent:nil];

    if (!isForgotTxt)
    {
        [self.vew  endEditing: YES];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using resignFirstResponder?